# PDF file with 6-column (multi) layout

Tags: php, pdf, layout, qr-code, fpdf

I need to create a pdf document with QR codes. I want to fit 6 QR codes in a row with border around them. But all I am getting is this:

[image]

As you can see it's putting them all in one row.

This is what I tried. I get data for my QR from a database, I make a QR code using phpqrcode library and then using FPDF I print the image on a PDF.

I know this is probably not the smartest solution but I need to generate QR codes and PDF in the same PHP script. Luckily, I didn't encounter any problems regarding that, since output are all different QR codes.

```
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $text = $data['Id']."_".$data['IdMesto'];

    $file = "codes/qr_".$text.".png";

    $ecc = 'H';
    $pixel_size = 20;
    $frame_size = 3;
  
    QRcode::png($text, $file, $ecc, $pixel_size, $frame_size);

    $pdf->Image($file,$pdf->GetX()+5,$pdf->GetY()+5,20,20,"png");
    $pdf->Cell(30,30,"",1,0);

    
}
```

Comment: What happens when you change the image size on the pdf image? `$pdf->Image($file,$pdf->GetX()+5,$pdf->GetY()+5,15,15,"png");`

Comment: @msmahon Same thing, only the image gets smaller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track of how many QR codes you have output and when the count reaches 6 tell fPDF to start a new line.

```
$qrcount = 0;
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

    if ($qrcount == 6) {
       $pdf->Ln();
       $qrcount = 0;
    }
    $text = $data['Id']."_".$data['IdMesto'];

    $file = "codes/qr_".$text.".png";

    $ecc = 'H';
    $pixel_size = 20;
    $frame_size = 3;
  
    QRcode::png($text, $file, $ecc, $pixel_size, $frame_size);

    $pdf->Image($file,$pdf->GetX()+5,$pdf->GetY()+5,20,20,"png");
    $pdf->Cell(30,30,"",1,0);
    $qrcount++;
    
}
```

Comment: thank you, I tried that, but it stacks them all in the first row

Comment: Is there more to the code being used than what you posted? The use of `$pdf-Image` should be producing the individual images so after 6 the `$pdf->Ln();` should emit a new line. Change `$pdf->Ln();` to `$pdf->Ln($pdf->GetY()+5);` and see if it helps.

Comment: I'm sorry, you were right, in front of this code I had some unnecessary fuctions that I tried before, but didn't work and it totally slipped my mind to remove them.

Comment: If my answer helped please consider accepting it. if you did need to use the modification in my comment above please let me know and I'll edit it into the answer.

Comment: The answer helped and there is no need to edit it, and also again thank you. Only problem that now occurs is with PageBreak or something like that: [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/PQ5iTL3) but it's a minor issue.

Comment: That's a problem similar to keeping track of how many images you have already output on a row. You know how "long" the page is so keep track of how many rows you have output and add a page break when you run out of room on a page. Hint, make sure that you are counting the height of the images plus any space between the rows. And make sure automatic page breaks are turned on.

Comment: Thank you, but I have already solved the problem and yes I used similar strategy. Condition where I counted how many Cells I have on a page and when the counter reaches a certain number I used `$pdf->AddPage()` manually. Also I blocked `$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false)`, because I found it as a solution to a similar program here on StackOverflow. 

Again, thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Change the cell size.

```
$pdf->Cell(20,20,"",1,0)
```